# +1 is in front of some cellular numbers how to remove +1

Tags: arrays

I have cellular phone numbers I need to run query against another table with celluar phone numbers but specific cells in the phone number column have +1 before the phone number and specific cells do not have +1 in front of cellular phone numbers.

Where specific cells in a column have +1 in front of the cellular phone number how to modify by removing +1 if exists.

Comment: which language are you programming in?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to make it more specific/clear (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Please read the description for the tag "arrays" you used here. And then step back, and think about what else we would need to give you a reasonable answer. You want us to spend our time to help you, so you please spend your time to come up with a reasonable question that can be answered. This one can't, by far.

Comment: Like: what program language. Are you talking about database tables? Etc ... and of course: +1 is the international code for the US. You absolutely have to know what country a phone number is supposed to belong to. Otherwise your data is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the cellular phone numbers are 10 digits in length. So, You can select the Phone numbers which are greater than the length of 10 and overwrite those values with the last 10 digits (length_Of_Cell_Value-10 to length_Of_Cell_Value). So that the exact phone number without the country code is overwritten at the respective cell value..